# php mysql where clause not reading variable

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I am starting to get furious here

`mysql_query` don't recognize my variable `$d1` even I tried to rename it

here is the code..

html:

```
<form action ="manageVessel.php" method ="POST">
  <select onchange ="this.form.submit();" class ="form-control" name ="ViewPositionCertificates">
      <option>Choose a Position </option>                                                       
      <?php
      $ViewPCertificates = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjob") or die("error" . mysql_error());
      while ($rwViewPCertificates = mysql_fetch_array($ViewPCertificates)) {
          ?>
          <option value =" <?php echo $rwViewPCertificates['jobName']; ?> "> <?php echo $rwViewPCertificates['jobName']; ?></option>  
      <?php } ?>

       </select>   
</form>
```

php:

```
   <?php if (isset($_POST['ViewPositionCertificates'])) { ?>
      <table class = "table table-bordered">
          <tr class ="bg-primary">
              <td> List of Certificates </td>
          </tr>
          <?php
          $d1 = $_POST['ViewPositionCertificates'];
          echo $_POST['ViewPositionCertificates'];
          $ViewCertificatesFP = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjobassigning WHERE jobName =  '$d1' ") or die("error" . mysql_error());

          while ($rwViewCertificatesFP = mysql_fetch_array($ViewCertificatesFP)) {

              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $rwViewCertificatesFP['Certificate'] . "</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
          }
          ?>

      </table>




  <?php } ?>
```

MYSQL WHERE clause is working fine when I used a string for example

```
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjobassigning WHERE jobName =  'MASTER' ") or die("error" . mysql_error());
```

but when I used a variable to assign `$_POST['ViewPositionCertificates']` to a variable MYSQL WHERE clause doesn't read it any help?

Comment: `$ViewCertificatesFP = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjobassigning WHERE jobName =  '{$d1}' ") or die("error" . mysql_error());` 

use this query
and a pair of avice, please prefer mysqli over mysql

Comment: As nobody said it I'll say it. Please **don't** use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and in the newly released PHP 7.0 deleted use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Also when handling user input use prepared statements otherwise your query is open for [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<option value ="<?php echo $rwViewPCertificates['jobName']; ?>"> <?php echo $rwViewPCertificates['jobName']; ?></option>   // remove xtra spaces from here......
```

Remove spaces from `value` attribute

Comment: thanks did not notice whitespace from value attribute

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
$ViewCertificatesFP = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjobassigning WHERE jobName =  '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($d1))."' ") or die("error" . mysql_error());
```

or

```
$ViewCertificatesFP = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjobassigning WHERE jobName =  '".addslashes(trim($d1))."' ") or die("error" . mysql_error());
```

Comment: I think there is some special character in value of "$d1" variable. Try using with mysql_real_escape_string() or addslashes()

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['ViewPositionCertificates'])) { ?>
    <table class = "table table-bordered">
        <tr class ="bg-primary">
            <td> List of Certificates </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $d1 = $_POST['ViewPositionCertificates'];
        echo $_POST['ViewPositionCertificates'];
        $ViewCertificatesFP = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjobassigning WHERE jobName =  '".$d1."' ") or die("error" . mysql_error());

        while ($rwViewCertificatesFP = mysql_fetch_array($ViewCertificatesFP)) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rwViewCertificatesFP['Certificate'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Change in select query syntax use single quote.

Comment: thanks for the response :) but I already tried that so far wont work? I also tried to restart my apache and mysql but it still don't work

Comment: Don't you know how to vote? Or you just need an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjobassigning WHERE jobName =  ".$_POST['ViewPositionCertificates'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not write variables inside single quotes, if you write it then PHP will consider it as string.
so your query will be 
`$ViewCertificatesFP = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjobassigning WHERE jobName = $d1 ") or die("error" . mysql_error());`

for more help , please read variable interpolation in PHP

Comment: Thanks for the response I already tried  that but I keep getting an error  Unknown column 'MASTER' in 'where clause' master is one of the rows in my database for column jobName

Comment: ok then please confirm  'MASTER' is column present in your MySQL table

Comment: please replace $d1 to  ' " .$d1. " '   , I think it will solve your  problem

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your query method it may help...

```
$ViewCertificatesFP = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjobassigning WHERE jobName =  '".$d1."' ") or die("error" . mysql_error());
```